# Sort a multidimensional array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am using laravel and  want to sort this array based on ['messages'] "updated_at" field. The array should show latest message on top.
I tried **array_multisort( array_column($yourArray, "price"), SORT_ASC, $yourArray )** but didn't work.

Here is my multidimensional array which I want to sort by date.

```
Array
(
    [current_page] => 1
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 236
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 91
                            [email] => demo3@test.com
                            [updated_at] => 2020-04-29 09:28:26
                        )

                    [messages] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 235
                    [description] => demo3
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 91
                            [email] => demo3@test.com
                            [updated_at] => 2020-04-29 09:28:26
                        )
                    [messages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 95
                                    [message] => Pickup message test
                                    [user_id] => 35
                                    [created_at] => 2020-04-28 12:28:18
                                    [updated_at] => 2020-04-28 12:28:18
                                )
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 215
                    [description] => Testing for messages
                    [user] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 35
                            [email] => test@outlook.com
                            [updated_at] => 2020-01-26 17:34:35
                        )

                    [messages] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 88
                                    [message] => Testing for the message if not sent by business first.
                                    [user_id] => 35
                                    [created_at] => 2020-04-28 12:15:14
                                    [updated_at] => 2020-04-28 12:15:14

                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 90
                                    [message] => Looks good.
                                    [user_id] => 69
                                    [created_at] => 2020-04-28 12:15:45
                                    [updated_at] => 2020-04-28 12:15:45

                                )


                        )

                )

        )
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use usort function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Write a callback comparing  the nested created_at attribute

Also if you have a laravel collection you can use

```
$collection = $collection->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Or if you are using eloquent you can order from SQL

```
Message::where(...)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(20)
```

From a user relation

```
$user->with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}]);
```

Comment: I am getting data from this 

```$claims = Claim::query();

$claims = $claims->where('status', $status);

$claims->load('user', 'item', 'item.category', 'actions', 'actions.user', 'messages', 'messages.user');
```
how can I use this

```$user->with(['messages' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}]);
```

Comment: do you need order only the messages or all collection?

Comment: I need to order all collection